# How to work out the degrees of freedom from R multiple regression output

Tags: r, multiple-regression, degrees-of-freedom

I have created a multiple regression in R and when i summarise the test, i get a table with coefficients and significance of individual variables in the model, followed the by the overall stats for the model (see below):

[image: R Output]

My question is, if i were to report the significance of the Coral Cover from the table above, what df would i use as? My gut feeling is it is either 2 (because there are 3 variables in the model; N-1) or 3  (because i *think* i may have read something saying it is just N).

Can anyone enlighten me to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single variables have the $t$-value given and it has df equal to those for the model residual. The total model has degrees of freedom equal to the number of parameters and the model residual df. All of these are printed out for you.

Comment: Thank you, so in this case the model residual produces a df of 9 so this would be the df for those t-values?

Comment: Yes that is correct